# Constraining some rows from LeastSquares to lines

Tags: fitting

For two matrices, `A` and `B`, with dimensions `{n,p}` and `{n,2}` respectively, `LeastSquares[A,B]` returns an matrix, `R`, with dimensions `{p,2}`.

But any row of `R` could be anywhere in the real plane. I want to constrain `R[[1]]` and `R[[-1]]` to two different lines. How should this be done?

The system is overdetermined, `n>p`

Comment: Seems like "random" cases will have them linearly independent. Trying to force this could be tricky, unless you have a criterion in mind for how far apart they must be. Determining what that might mean, for your purposes, would be the first step.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of one way to proceed.

```
n = 3; p = 4;
amat = Array[a, {n, p}];
bvec1 = Array[b1, n];
bvec2 = Array[b2, n];
rvec1 = Array[r1, p];
rvec2 = Array[r2, p];
sol = Solve[amat.Transpose[{rvec1, rvec2}] == Transpose[{bvec1, bvec2}], 
  Flatten[{rvec1, rvec2}]]
```

The solution you get from this comes with a warning that "Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables." This is precisely what you want to exploit. For the given `n` and `p`, you have free variables `r1[1]` and `r2[1]`, which can be set to any desired value, thus giving the constraint that you specify. As you change `n` and `p`, you may have a larger or smaller number of free variables.